# C# Replace base class summary comment without overriding variable

Tags: c#, inheritance, comments, summary

I'm trying to replace the base class variable comment with a new comment, how can I achieve this?

Here's a built-in class for example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    /// <summary>Built-in class variable 1.</summary>
    public float var1;
    ...
}
```

I want to add the summary of `var1` with `<para>Adding comment to built-in variable.</para>` in a Derived Class with the code below:

```
class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    /// <summary>Built-in class variable 1.</summary>
    /// <para>Adding comment to built-in variable.</para>
    public float var1;
    ...
}
```

And there's a message said:

> 'DerivedClass' hides inherited member 'BaseClass.var1'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Seems like I had failed to replace the comment in my Derived Class.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do both `TTL` in the base and derive serve the same functionality? Or do they behave differently beetween `TTLClass` and `TTTClass`.

Comment: Yes, they have the same functionality, but I wish to add some comments to make the usage description more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things working against you:

1. You cannot "override" comments in derived classes.  The comments are tied to the class where the associated member is defined.  The only way to change comments to inherited members is to override them.
2. Fields are not overrideable.  you can *access* them from the derived class, but since they are data only and have no implementation, there's nothing to "override".

> I wish to add some comments to make the usage description more clearly

You mean usage *within the class* or usage *by the consumer*?

Some options:

- Add comments to the class itself clarifying what the intended usage of that (and possible other fields) is.
- Add comments in the methods that use it stating the different usage of TTL?
- Use a different field in the base class? If the usage is different it may be better not to re-use the base property to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to just override the base comment, but your derived class could have a property that simply gets and sets the base property, and then you could give it a new comment.

```
class BaseClass
{
    /// <summary>Time To Live.</summary>
    public float TTL;

    ...
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    /// <summary>Time To Live.</summary>
    /// <para>Also stops ticking after living time is longer than TTL.</para>
    public float TTL
    {
        get { return base.TTL; }
        set { base.TTL = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there a possible way without using `property`? Maybe adding a comment line or something?